# Swing to JavaFX - equivalent of overriding a button's isEnabled() method?

Tags: java, swing, javafx, isenabled

In Swing we can do something like

```
JButton button = new JButton("button") {
  public boolean isEnabled() {
    return ...condition...;
  }
};
```

Since isDisable() / isDisabled() of a JavaFX Button is declared final - what is the equivalent for enabling or disabling a JavaFX button conditionally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express your condition as an `ObservableValue<Boolean>`, and do

```
button.disableProperty().bind(condition);
```

For example, if you wanted to disable the button when a text field was empty, you could do

```
button.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.isEmpty(textField.textProperty()));
```

or, if you are still using JavaFX 2.2,

```
button.disableProperty().bind(new BooleanBinding() {
    { bind(textField.textProperty()); }
    @Override
    public boolean computeValue() {
        return textField.getText().isEmpty() ;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank your for the quick reply! In Java7 I put the condition into getValue() of a new ObservableValue<Boolean> instance and bound it to the button using your expression. But getValue() gets only called once and disables my button forever. When using ObservableBooleanValue and put my condition into get() it works :-) but now the button is displayed always as disabled although it is clickable. So, when do I have to use ObservableValue<Boolean> and when ObservableBooleanValue? And how do I get the button being displayed correctly?

Comment: What is the condition?

Comment: return pco.offset == 0; where pco.offset may change after clicking the button itself or another button being part of my application (these are simple next and previous navigation buttons). At start, pco.offset is 0.

Comment: So you need to create an `ObservableValue<Boolean>` that is invalidated whenever `pco.offset` changes. The simplest way is to implement `pco.offset` as an `IntegerProperty` and do `button.disableProperty().bind(pco.offsetProperty().isEqualTo(0));` See the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm#JFXBD107) if you are unfamiliar with properties and bindings.

Comment: Ok, I implemented pco.offset as a SimpleIntegerProperty and it works perfectly, thank you! One more question: Since my code must be compatible to JRE7, when can I use the isEqualTo(0) syntax in your last comment, and when do I have to use the BooleanBinding syntax with the anonymous class you mentioned above?

Comment: `IntegerProperty.isEqualTo(int)` dates (way) back to JavaFX2.0, so you can use it with JRE7. The method that was introduced in Java 8 that I used in the answer was `Bindings.isEmpty(ObservableStringValue)`, so I showed a longer (lower-level) option there. (Basically, if it compiles for you in Java 7/JavaFX 2.2, you can use it.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. For another use case, how could IntegerProperty.isEqualTo(0) be adapted using a BooleanProperty? There is nothing like BooleanProperty.isEqualTo(false), so I'd have to instantiate an ObservableBooleanValue first, wouldn't I?

Comment: Something else comes into my mind: How would I trigger a re-evaluation and a possible re-rendering in a "best practise" way if the condition variable cannot be wrapped by a JavaFx property?